# Best way to loop through array and group consecutive numbers in another array SWIFT 4?

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way using SWIFT 4 to loop through an array of numbers, get the range of any consecutive numbers and add those to a new array.  I could do the standard loop checks but I believe I can use a map filter? -- can someone point me in the right direction?

Beginning:

```
myNumbersArray:[Int] = [1,2,3,4,10,11,15,20,21,22,23]
```

Wanted result:

```
newNumbersArray = [
   [1,2,3,4],
   [10,11],
   [15],
   [20,21,22,23]
]
```

I will post my solution if I figure it out...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My suggestion is `IndexSet` where consecutive items are stored as ranges.

- Create the index set from the array.
- Get the `rangeView`.
- Map the ranges to arrays.

---

```
let myNumbersArray = [1,2,3,4,10,11,15,20,21,22,23]
let indexSet = IndexSet(myNumbersArray)
let rangeView = indexSet.rangeView
let newNumbersArray = rangeView.map { Array($0.indices) }
```

Comment: `rangeView.map { Array($0.indices) }`

Answer (score 8):

This would work also with negative integers:

```
extension BidirectionalCollection where Element: BinaryInteger, Index == Int {
    var consecutivelyGrouped: [[Element]] { 
        return reduce(into: []) {
            $0.last?.last?.advanced(by: 1) == $1 ? 
            $0[index(before: $0.endIndex)].append($1) :
            $0.append([$1]) 
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
let numbers = [-5,-4,-2,0,1,3,4,10,11,15,20,21,22,23]
let grouped = numbers.consecutivelyGrouped  // [[-5, -4], [-2], [0, 1], [3, 4], [10, 11], [15], [20, 21, 22, 23]]
```

Comment: great answer.. Saved lots of time.

Comment: If I only want to return consecutive values if the amount of values are a certain size, what needs to be added? Lets say I want to return an array of consecutive integers only if there are more than two consecutive integers per each consecutive integer array, i.e. only return [20,21,22,23] @Leo Dabus

Comment: I'm thinking of reiterating numbers.consecutivelyGrouped using an if when loop but that sounds like double the work and less efficient

Comment: you just need to filter the sub arrays by count > 2 `let grouped = numbers.consecutivelyGrouped.filter{$0.count > 2} `

Comment: if you would like to do it on the fly `var consecutivelyGrouped: [[Element]] {
        var counter = 0
        return reduce(into: []) {
            if $0.last?.last?.advanced(by: 1) == $1 {
                $0[index(before: $0.endIndex)].append($1)
                counter += 1
            } else {
                if !$0.isEmpty, counter < 3 { $0.removeLast() }
                $0.append([$1])
                counter = 1
            }
        }
    }` it could also be done by checking the sub array count but it is more efficient to add a counter

Comment: Doesn't work If it is not sorted

Comment: @CrackIt Thats obvious

Answer (score 6):

While using `IndexSet` according to [@vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52019669/1801544) is a good idea, it works only in your case (consecutive and positive integers), and it may be not your purpose to use indices. It's a little hacky to use a similar kind of objects for that, but does nicely the job.

A possible way is to use `reduce()`:

```
let reduced = myNumbersArray.reduce([[Int]]()) { (current, next) -> [[Int]] in
    var result = current
    //Retrieve the last sequence, check if the current - last item of sequence is 1 to know if they are consecutive or not
    if var lastSequence = result.last, let last = lastSequence.last, next-last == 1 {
        lastSequence.append(next)
        result[result.endIndex-1] = lastSequence
        return result
    } else { //It's not => New array of its own
        result.append([next])
        return result
    }
}
print("reduced: \(reduced)")
```

Output:

```
$>reduced: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 11], [15], [20, 21, 22, 23]]
```

As suggested by [@Leo Dabus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52019449/best-way-to-loop-through-array-and-group-consecutive-numbers-in-another-array-sw/52019769?noredirect=1#comment90989934_52019769), with `reduce(into:)`:

```
let reducedInto = myNumbersArray.reduce(into: [[Int]]()) { (result, next) in
    //Retrieve the last sequence, check if the current - last item of sequence is 1
    if var lastSequence = result.last, let last = lastSequence.last, next-last == 1 {
        lastSequence.append(next)
        result[result.endIndex-1] = lastSequence
    } else { //It's not => New array of its own
        result.append([next])
    }
}
print("reducedInto: \(reducedInto)")
```

Output:

```
$>reducedInto: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 11], [15], [20, 21, 22, 23]]
```

Comment: You can use `reduce(into:)`
 if you are coding in Swift 4

Comment: @larme great answer! By tweaking the solution a bit, your answer can be applied to an array of custom objects / models, to filter out based on a specific property of the object. Thanks for sharing this

Comment: @NitinAlabur it can be applied to a lot of thing. It’s just that I made it more explicit than Leo Dabius’s answer.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are not familiar with map and indexset check this:

```
var arr = [0,1,2,4,6,7,9]
var previousIndex = 0
var count = 0
var arrayDict : [Int:[Int]] = [:]
for (index,data) in arr.enumerated() {
  if index == (arr.count - 1) {
     arrayDict[count] = Array(arr[previousIndex ..< index + 1])
     break
  }
  if arr[index + 1] - data != 1 {
    arrayDict[count] = Array(arr[previousIndex ..< index + 1])
    previousIndex = index + 1
    count += 1
  }
}
print(arrayDict)
```

The logic is that i'm iterating over the elements of the given array and each time checking whether the value at that index is not less than value at index + 1 by 1, if it is then I am splitting the array using Array slice and adding it in a dictionary having a key which is given by the variable 'count'. the variable previous Index holds the end index of previous split so that next split starts from previousIndex to the current index