# Populate objects in TableView sections by months order

Tags: ios, swift, date, tableview

I have an array of objects that contain Date property. I want to distribute them in UITableView sections according to their month by month order. How I can do that?

My model:

```
class Birthday: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var date: Date = Date()
    @objc dynamic var dayLeft: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var userImageData: Data?
}
```

First I use the next code with DateFormatter:

```
var grouped: [String: [Birthday]] = [:]

grouped = Dictionary(grouping: birthdaysList) { item -> String in
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: item.date)
    let date = calendar.date(from: components) ?? Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)
    return date.monthAsString()
}

extension Date {
    func monthAsString() -> String {
            let df = DateFormatter()
            df.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MMM")
            return df.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

Then I use:

```
struct Section {
    let month: String
    let birthdays: [Birthday]
}

    var sections: [Section] = []
    let keys = Array(grouped.keys)
    sections = keys.map({Section(month: $0, birthdays: grouped[$0]!)})
```

But I need to sort month names in order. January, february etc. How this can be done?

I try to return tuple from my code, but get error

Declared closure result '(String, Int)' is incompatible with contextual type 'String'

```
grouped = Dictionary(grouping: birthdaysList) { item -> (String, Int) in
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: item.date)
    let date = calendar.date(from: components) ?? Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)
    return (date.monthAsString(), components.month!)
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52043162/how-can-i-group-fetched-dates-by-month/52043752#52043752

Comment: Thanks. But may be you can provide code example for my case?

Comment: Actually the linked answer contains an example. Group the array to a dictionary by year and month.

Comment: I added to my question code example you provided, but anyway cannot get how to get month names in sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a wrapper struct

```
struct Section {
    let month : String
    let birthdays : [Birthday]
}
```

then map the grouped dictionary to an array of `Section`

```
let keys = Array(grouped.keys)
let sections = keys.map({Section(month: $0, birthdays: grouped[$0]!)})
```

`sections` represent the sections, `birthdays` the rows, `month` the section header titles.

---

Edit:

To be able to sort the months by their ordinal number return the number in front of the month name

```
grouped = Dictionary(grouping: birthdaysList) { item -> String in
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: item.date)
    let date = calendar.date(from: components) ?? Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)
    return  "\(components.month!)_" + date.monthAsString()
}
```

And modify the mapping code

```
let keys = grouped.keys.sorted{$0.localizedStandardCompare($1) == .orderedAscending}
let sections = keys.map({Section(month: $0.components(separatedBy:"_").last!, birthdays: grouped[$0]!)})
```

Comment: I get error: Cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to expected argument type '[Birthday]'

Comment: Use Swift native collection types.

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: The error is not related to the given code, maybe you use `NSArray` somewhere or you forgot to downcast a type properly.

Comment: But how I can sort months in order? I want january will be first, then february etc. How this can be done?

Comment: Rather than returning a string return a tuple `(String, Int)` from the closure. The integer value is the `month` component, then you are able to sort the array properly.

Comment: I try, bug get error: Declared closure result '(String, Int)' is incompatible with contextual type 'String'

Comment: If you declare `item -> (String, Int) in` you have to return `return (date.monthAsString(), components.month!)` and vice versa.

Comment: I try, but anyway I get error: Declared closure result '(String, Int)' is incompatible with contextual type 'String'

Comment: I added info to the question. In grouped = Dictionary(grouping: birthdaysList)