# Array of Integers to Arrays of Ranges

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, algorithm, sorting

**My Task:** 
I need to divide the Array into several Arrays of Arrays with the following properties:

1. every subarray is a range of continuous integer. As example `[1,2,3,4,5]` will be `[[1,5]]`.
2. When there are no contiguous integer create a new subarray. As example `[1,2,4,5]` will be `[[1,2], [4,5]]`

*Example:*

If I have this Array of Integers - `[0, 1, 5, 6, 3, 7]`

Expected Result - `[[0, 1], [3], [5, 7]]`

I already tried this:

```
let array: [Int] = [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

var group: [[Int]] = []
var temp: [Int] = [Int]()

for (index, element) in array.enumerated() {
    if index + 1 < array.count {
        let nextElement = array[index + 1]
        let step = nextElement - element

//        temp.append(element)

        if(step) == 1 { // Until it's in range
            temp.append(element)
        } else { // One-by-one
            temp.append(element)
            group.append(temp)

            temp = [Int]()
            group.append([nextElement])
        }
    } else {
        print(index)
    }
}

print(group)
```

From my code, I get this result - `[[0, 1], [3]]`

Comment: What is the result of your attempt? What issue are you having? Please update your question with details about your problem.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't get I result I need, this is my result: [[0, 1], [3]]. ok, I'll update my question.

Comment: For [0, 1, 5, 6, 3, 7], shouldn't the expected result be [[0, 1], [3], [5,7]] ?

Comment: @sidmishraw why? where is 6? :) it's must be [[0, 1], [3], [5, 6, 7]]

Comment: @F.Sviatoslav If the result of [0,1,2,3,4,5] is [[0,5]] then the result of [0,1,3,5,6,7] should be [[0,1],[3],[5,7]].

Comment: @rmaddy yes, now it's right

Comment: @F.Sviatoslav What's right? Your question still shows conflicting requirements.

Comment: Are we guaranteed that the input is sorted?

Comment: The bug is that once `index + 1` reaches `array.count`, you hit your `else` block, print the index, but you never persisted your last `temp` value to by appending it to your `group`.

Comment: Closely relatad: [Best way to loop through array and group consecutive numbers in another array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52019449/best-way-to-loop-through-array-and-group-consecutive-numbers-in-another-array-sw)

Answer (score 2):

There is an API, [IndexSet](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/indexset):

It's not clear what you want, your examples are ambiguous.

If you want an array of ranges

```
let indexSet = IndexSet(array)
let rangeView = indexSet.rangeView
let group = rangeView.map { $0.indices.startIndex..<$0.indices.endIndex }
```

If you want a grouped array by ranges

```
let indexSet = IndexSet(array)
let rangeView = indexSet.rangeView
let group = rangeView.map { Array($0.indices) }
```

Comment: Nice but I'm guessing this is a homework problem and using `IndexSet` is cheating.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best approach I found:

```
let array: [Int] = [0, 1, 5, 6, 3, 7].sorted();

var group: [[Int]] = []
var temp: [Int] = [Int]()
var lastElement: Int = -1;
for (index, element) in array.enumerated() {
    if lastElement == -1 {
      temp.append(element);
    }
    else {
      if element - lastElement == 1 {
        temp.append(element);
      }
      else {
        group.append(temp);
        temp = [Int]();
        temp.append(element);
      }
    }
    lastElement = element;
}
if temp.count > 0 {
  group.append(temp);
}

print(group)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Rather than manually managing indexes, I use two iterators. One which advances along denoting the "start" of runs, and one which races ahead to find the "ends" of runs.

I've gentrified my code to work over any `Sequence` (not just `Array`), and any `Strideable` type (any type that defines `distance(to:)`, not necessarily just `Int`).

```
extension Sequence where Element: Strideable {
    func splitConsequtiveRuns() -> [[Element]] {
        var runs = [[Element]]()

        var runStartIterator = self.makeIterator()

        while let startElement = runStartIterator.next() {
            var runEndIterator = runStartIterator
            var prevElement = startElement

            var run = [startElement]
            while let nextElement = runEndIterator.next(),
                prevElement.distance(to: nextElement) == 1 {
                _ = runStartIterator.next() // advance the "start" iterator, to keep pace

                prevElement = nextElement // update this, for use in then next loop's comparison
                run.append(nextElement)
            }

            runs.append(run)
        }

        return runs
    }
}

let array: [Int] = [0...3, 8...8, 10...15].flatMap { $0 }
print(array.splitConsequtiveRuns()) // => [[0, 1, 2, 3], [8], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```